bear data set: glm or glmm?
I have a dataset where I am trying to determine the speed of bears depending on their sex, the year and the season. Some of my bears have multiple seasons of data: out of 79 bears, 19 had data for two seasons, and 6 had data for 3 seasons.
I was initially thinking of using a generalized linear model (glm) to model the speed of the bears, something like this:
speed =  sex + year + sex:season
but given the amount of repeated data, I'm wondering whether it would be better to have a general linear mixed model (glmm) instead, with bear ID added as random effect.
I'd prefer to keep the original glm, as it's simpler to work with. Because most bears have only one season of data, I'm also not sure this dataset warrants having a random effect added since most levels of this random effect will only have one observation. However I'm also concerned about the repeated data violating the law of independence. Any thoughts on this?
